# Are Bulletproofs fully implemented into liquid?

Tags: blockstream, liquid

Blockstream themselves released a paper in 2018 about a more efficient range proof and Calles IT Bulletproofs. I'm wondering if it is already fully integrated into the liquid sidechain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the Liquid system isn't using Bulletproofs yet.

The code has been written to use them, but switching over will require more review, and a hardfork upgrade once deployed.